# Join Two Project By Asp.net Signalr

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to connect between two project by signalr,what can i do?.
For example, I have a system announcements and when the user adds the ad shows him in another website, notice of the announcement but the website who added upon announcement differs from the other site.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR has built in functionality for using Redis to share state across multiple servers. This is generally meant to be used for multiple instances of the same site, but as long as you use the same hub name and event key you should be able to get what you're looking for.

Here is a link to an article I recently used to set up something similar:
[Scaling SignalR with Redis](http://blog.mirajavora.com/scaling-signalr-with-redis)